# building a stock ticker widget on jive api error

Tags: api, widget, yahoo, finance, jive

I added a real-time stock widget to a client’s `Jive` site that is using an HTML widget. The code uses the `Jive` native `jQuery` library to pull `JSONP` data from Yahoo using their `YQL API`. This widget is written to work with only `1` stock symbol. If requested, I can modify it to pull in multiple symbols.

I keep getting an error for `if (res.query.results)`. It says it is undefined. If anybody knows of a good stock HTML widget with just price and name of symbol: Please help. I am digging deep in Google.

Console output:

```
render-widget.jspa?size=1&frameID=262901&widgetType=7&containerID=1327&containerType=700&inFrame=1:173 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
at Object.success (render-widget.jspa?size=1&frameID=262901&widgetType=7&containerID=1327&containerType=700&inFrame=1:173)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at x (jquery.min.js:4)
at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:4)

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This version has been tested to work in Jive 4.0.15 and 5.0. It should work in Jive 4.5 but has not been tested
// Add the stock symbol here
  var yourStockSymbol = 'LIFE';
</script>

<div id="stock_miniQuote_head" class="ajaxtrigger"><span id="stockSymbol"></span>&nbsp;(common stock)</div>

<div id="stock_miniQuote">
<div id="stockIndicator"><p>Retrieving stock information...</p></div>


    <div class="stock_divider">

      <div id="stock_left">
        <span class="stock_label">Price</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong">$<span id="stockAsk"></span></strong><br/>
      </div>


      <div id="stock_right">
        <span class="stock_label">Change</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChange"></span></strong><br />
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChangePercent"></span></strong><br />
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>


    </div>

      <div id="stock_body">

      <div id="stock_body_content">
        <span class="stock_label">Volume</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockVolume"></span></strong>
        <br /><br />
        <span class="stock_label">Average Daily Volume</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockAvgVolume"></span></strong>
        <br /><br />
        <span class="stock_label">52 Week Range</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockRange"></span></strong>       

      </div>

      <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>



</div>  



<style>

#stockIndicator { 
  text-align:left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.ajaxtrigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer; 
  cursor: hand;
}

#stock_miniQuote_head {
  background-color:#464A55;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

#stock_miniQuote {
  border-bottom-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
  border-bottom-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  border-left-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-left-style:solid;
  border-left-width:1px;
  border-right-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-width:1px;
  border-top-color:initial;
  border-top-style:none;
  border-top-width:initial;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:10px;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
}

.stock_divider {
  border-bottom:1px solid #B2B0AD; padding-bottom:5px;
}

#stock_left {
  float:left; width:35%; height:50px; border-right:1px solid #B2B0AD; padding:0 15px;
}

#stock_right {
  float:right; width:*; padding:0 20px; vertical-align:text-top;
}

.stock_label {
  font-size:14px;
}

.stock_strong {
  font-size:17px;
}

#stock_body {
  padding:10px 0 15px;
}

#stock_body_content {
  float:left; width:170px; padding:0 15px;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

if ($('#jive-widgets-browser').css('display') == 'block') {
// Do Nothing as we are in edit mode

} else {
// Build the URL to Yahoo YQL services
var q = escape('select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + yourStockSymbol + '")');
var theURL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + q + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?";


$(document).ready(function(){
// Load function on launch
  $("#stockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(theURL);

// Function for refreshing the stock by clicking on the title header
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
  $("#stockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(theURL);
    return false;
  });

// Function to add commas to numbers for volume
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

// Main function to make JSON request to Yahoo for stock information
  function doAjax(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      var s = data.query.results;
          if(s){
      if(s.quote.Change > 0) {
        // Change the change text to green
        $('#stockChange').css({'color': 'green'});
        $('#stockChangePercent').css({'color': 'green'});
      } else {
        // Change the change text to red
        $('#stockChange').css({'color': 'red'});
        $('#stockChangePercent').css({'color': 'red'});
      }

      // This is where we add the JSON values back into the HTML above
      $('#stockSymbol').html(s.quote.symbol);
      $('#stockAsk').html(s.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
      $('#stockChange').html(s.quote.Change);
      $('#stockChangePercent').html(s.quote.ChangeinPercent);
      $('#stockVolume').html(numberWithCommas(s.quote.Volume));
      $('#stockAvgVolume').html(numberWithCommas(s.quote.AverageDailyVolume));
      $('#stockRange').html(s.quote.YearRange);

      $("#stockIndicator").hide();

          } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
      $("#stockIndicator").show();
            $("#stockIndicator").html(errormsg);
          }
        }
      });

  }


  }); //end ready function

} //end first else





</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Finance APi was turned off earlier this year, including accessing this information via YQL queries.  You will need to find an alternate service and update our code accordingly.

There was another thread about this here, [Yahoo Finance API changes (2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057580/yahoo-finance-api-changes-2017)

Comment: I found another service - how do i conver this into html5 widget.