# Some ETF Tickers Not Working in Yahoo Finance DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I'm gathering data from a bunch of ETFs through Yahoo Finance using Pandas-Datareader and I'm getting odd errors with a handful of the tickers even though the data seems available.  The code is very simple:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)

for ticker in TICKERS:
     f = dr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

and works for most of my tickers but not all:

```
EMLP GDVD (Failed to get data for GDVD) AMZA RFDI ARKK ARKW SECT (Failed to get data for SECT)
```

EMLP works fine.  Datareader produces urls like this [url for GDVD](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GDVD?crumb=bDrHp%2FU0RVC&interval=1d&period2=1483343999&events=history&period1=1262332800) even though the [historical data for GDVD](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GDVD/history?p=GDVD) is available on the website.  I see the following error in Chrome using the GDVD url:

```
{"finance": {"error": {"code": "Unauthorized","description": "Invalid cookie"}}}
```

Is there a way to get historical prices for these tickers?  The full list of failed tickers in case anyone can see a pattern:

```
 ['GDVD', 'SECT', 'DWLD', 'CCOR', 'DFNL', 'DUSA', 'AIEQ', 'CACG', 'QSY', 'ACT', 'TAXR', 'TTAI', 'FLIO', 'FMDG', 'VGFO', 'FFSG', 'LRGE', 'YLDE', 'VESH', 'DEMS', 'SQZZ']
```

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057580/yahoo-finance-api-changes-2017).

Comment: Yeah.  I'm Yahoo's lack of support is not the issue, but it maybe.   I'm getting a little desperate as Google's API is also no longer supported and I'm running out of APIs that work with datareader.

Comment: Historical prices relative to when?

Comment: I'm looking for about 5-7 years of weekly or monthly prices for those tickers with that much history available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the yahoo_fin package, I was able to get the data for the tickers you listed.  Check out this link: http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/.

My code looks like this:

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_data

tickers =  ['GDVD', 'SECT', 'DWLD', 'CCOR', 'DFNL', 'DUSA', 'AIEQ', 'CACG',
            'QSY', 'ACT', 'TAXR', 'TTAI', 'FLIO', 'FMDG', 'VGFO', 'FFSG', 
            'LRGE', 'YLDE', 'VESH', 'DEMS', 'SQZZ']

stocks = {}

for ticker in tickers:

    stocks[ticker] = get_data(ticker)
```

So the data gets stored into a dictionary, where the keys are the tickers, and the values are the data frames containing each stock's data.

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary comprehension, like this:

```
stocks = {ticker : get_data(ticker) for ticker in tickers}
```

If you want to collapse all of the data sets into a single data frame, you could use the functools package like this:

```
from functools import reduce

combined = reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), stocks.values())
```