# Getting urllib HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x

I need help to see why i am getting error.

`Error = urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

Below is my python code.

```
from urllib import request as R

goog_url = 'http://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1540765774&period2=1543447774&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=.nIDyrXVXTp'


def download_stock_data(csv_url):
    response = R.urlopen(csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'goog.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()


download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that you need some token (401 is `Unauthorized`) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092983)